# Using Mongoose to findbyid and update sibling

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to locate a reference to another schema and update a sibling field. Specifically, I'm trying to manipulate the hasResponded field below based on a particular 'survey' ObjectId.

My schema looks like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  // some other stuff

  surveys: [{
      survey: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Survey'
      },
      hasResponded: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
      }
  }]

});
```

Comment: So you basically ask how to find all the users that have a particular survey id in their survey array? (and then updating their corresponding hasResponded field?)

Comment: Just a single user in this case, but I would also be interested in updating a similar field for all users that have a particular survey id as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a survey id, simply search for all the users that have this particular id in the array.
Something like that:

```
Users.find({surveys: { "$elemMatch": { type: <ID> } } });
```

Then, iterate through the users and their corresponding survey array to find the ones that match the id you gave.

Got to say I would structure this db a little different if this query takes place often.

Make a new Schema - UserSurveys that holds the id of the user and the survey + hasResponded. Like this:

```
var UserSurveySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    survey_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Survey'}
    hasResponded: {type:Boolean, 'default':false}
    ...
});
```

You might also want to keep an index on the user and survey ids.
Then, it will be much easier to update the field, requests will take much shorter times.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. Yes it certainly does. Thanks a lot for this. I'm going to make a new schema like you suggested.

Comment: UPDATE: Restructured things with a new UserSurvey schema and it worked out really well. Thanks again.